# redirect address to directory htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Pretty straight forward, I have an address www.example.com, and I need to redirect it to a subfolder which the actual website resides in.

I figured out how to redirect a http protocol request to https but this one I couldn't from what I've read.

This is my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/subfolder/ [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: when www.exapmle.com is entered it need to be directed (to everyone) to www.example.com/subfolder, after that, to the https eventually (I figured the https part as you can see)

Comment: eventually show https://www.example.com, that would be great

Comment: See this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: I tried that exactly and it didn't redirect it

Answer (score 0):

Use a Negative lookahead in regex like:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!subfolder/)(.*) http://www.example.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: which means...? What happened?

Comment: I may have missed a slash try `RewriteRule ^(?!subfolter/)(.*)$ http://www.example.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
If you have doubts you can check the regex in sites like debuggex.com